# Open-Minded yet Objective Opinion on CMS User-Friendliness

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla, content-management-system

I have worked with a number of `Content Management Systems` out there (and even built my own when necessary). I know what works best for me, but since *I don't pay myself to make CMS sites*, what I think matters quite little.

I know `CMS` isn't necessarily *one-size-fits-all* so "XYZ is the best!" isn't going to cut it. I'm **hoping** to get some *demographic associated* information as well.

eg.

- `CMS 1` is easy to develop in, but can be cumbersome for n00b admins.
- `CMS 2` is great for stay at home moms to admin, but lacks all the good plugins.
- `CMS 3` I've heard good things about this, but it's not my personal favorite.
- etc

Some will say that this question is quite *subjective*, and while I can agree, there is still a very **GOOD** answer out there and I would like to get that answer from the people who work with `CMS` technology as a profession.

If you have *prized information* you would like to share with me, **please keep in mind** that there is a **three-fold** focus on a) `The administration` b) `The end-user` and c) `The development` with the administration (the one usually shelling out the $$) being the most *important* to my question.

**Thank You** for giving your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this question is that your 3 categories 1) administration 2) end-user 3) development aren't nearly descriptive enough.  If you really want to evaluate a CMS you need to ask "administering what?", "end-user management of what?", "developing what?".

--

The most effective tool I've seen for evaluating Content Management Systems is [well composed user stories](http://blogs.telerik.com/teampulse/posts/11-07-28/thoughts-on-agile-user-stories-and-high-bandwidth-communication.aspx).  For these stories, start with an audience and then describe an objective.

**As a PHP developer,** I'm creating a web site for a small real estate company.  They want to post their home listings to their website.  However, historically they keep these listings in an Excel spreadsheet.  They want to upload their existing spreadsheet to publish their listings to the website.  In addition, they have static website content (company information, staff, etc.) that occasionally needs to be edited.  I need a simple easy-to-use CMS that works on low-cost shared hosting that I can also extend to handle the uploaded spreadsheets.

**As a marketing director,** I'm struggling to manage our various online publishing channels.  This includes our web site, our mobile iPhone app, our Facebook page, our Twitter account and our bi-weekly newsletter.  Currently, when we publish a news item we need to manually cross post the same bit of content across each publishing channel.  I want our CMS to help us "create once" and then publish everywhere.  It would also be ideal if the CMS allowed us to schedule this publishing differently for each channel.

**As a website administrator,** we have a very large organization and lots of content contributors.  To manage all of this we have a content governance model that includes a hierarchy of contributors and editors who approve these content edits.  In addition, no content edit can be approved by its creator.  All content edits must be reviewed by someone else.  Once approved, the changes must be synced to our production environment.  This environment involves a total of 10 web servers and 2 distinct regional data locations.  I want a CMS that allows us to enforce our content governance model and easily deploy content changes.

--

You've tagged your question (Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal), but I've seen user stories that would severely challenge these CMS's.  In other cases, they are a perfect fit.  The "friendliness" of a CMS is subjective based on your requirements and the type of user-stories the CMS creators had in mind.  WordPress, as an example, is definitely easy, but it's also limited.  In fact, it's easy because it's use-case is so narrowly defined.

Anyone who would reply to this question with something like "Drupal is the most friendly for developers" would scare me.  This suggests a developer who hasn't been involved with a lot of diverse projects.  However, if we're just giving opinions, then we get a lot of user-friendly kudos for [Sitefinity CMS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCnYb4MbYD8).

Best wishes.

Comment: Thank you for your input. You effectively covered a number of areas I missed. I'm curious to know what other scalable `CMS` you've used and what led you to `Sitefinity`?